# Hibernate repeated column exception - 'username' declared twice for one-to-many related entities

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

Got classical Hibernate problem:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: entry.Authority column: username (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

**users.hbm.xml:**

```
<class name="entry.User" table="users">
    <property name="username" column="username"/>
    <set name="authorities" table="authorities" lazy="false" cascade="all">
        <key column="username" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="entry.Authority"/>
    </set>
```

**authorities.hbm.xml:**

```
    <class name="entry.Authority" table="authorities">
        <id name="id"/>
        <property name="username" column="username"/>
    </class>
```

Tried classical solution:

```
<property name="username" column="username"  insert="false" update="false"/>
```

Got:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'username' doesn't have a default value
```

Why I can't specify `username` twice in .xml?
As I understand this declaration `<property name="username" column="username"/>` relates to `User` and `<key column="username" not-null="true"/>` relates to `Authorities`
.So why they clash?
How can it be fixed with minimum invasion?

**EDITED:**

```
    <class name="entry.User" table="users">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="username"/>     
        <set name="authorities" table="authorities" lazy="false" cascade="all" inverse="true">
            <key column="username" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="entry.Authority"/>
        </set>
...
```

and

```
<class name="entry.Authority" table="authorities">
    <id name="id"/>
    <property name="username" column="username"/>
    <property name="authority" column="authority"/>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="entry.User">
             <column name="username"/>
     </many-to-one>
</class>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the key definition in users.hbm.xml `<key column="username" not-null="true"/>` you already handle the column username in Authorities. The line `<property name="username" column="username"/>` in authorities.hbm.xml is superfluous, even if used in many-to-one. Every time you load/update or insert the instances of Authorities **via** Users, the field is handled automatically by Hibernate. If you define the field also in authorities.hbm.xml then it is set twice - that's why you got your error message.

If you by some special reasons really want to have the username also in authorities.hbm.xml, then you have to specify insert/update = false (as you already did) and a default value to avoid your error message (even if the default never is used). For example

```
<property name="username" insert="false" update="false">
  <column="username" default="anyValue"/>
</property>
```

But I would simply recommend this:

```
<class name="entry.Authority" table="authorities">
  <id name="id"/>
  <property name="authority" column="authority"/>
  <many-to-one name="user" class="entry.User">
         <column name="username"/>
   </many-to-one>
</class>
```

---

Added after your comment:

Now I see a problem in your new mapping: the `<key>` element has to reference to the key of the parent table, and that is not the case. The key in the Users table is id, but you use a normal property Username as the foreign key in Authority. There are two possibilities to resolve this:

1) You make Username the key of Users (drop column id and define the key in Users as

```
<id name="username">
 <column="username"/>
</id>
```

(I'm not sure if in this case in new instances of Authority hibernate will set the member username automatically or if you have to do it manually.)

**new:** Here is the complete mapping (not tested):

```
<class name="entry.User" table="users">
  <id name="username" type="String">
    <column="username"/>
  </id>
  <property name="password" column="password" type="String"/>
  <property name="enabled" column="enabled" type="boolean"/>

  <set name="authorities" table="authorities" lazy="false" cascade="all" inverse="true">
    <key column="username" not-null="true"/>
    <one-to-many class="entry.Authority"/>
  </set>
</class>
```

2) You make id the foreign key in Authority:
In users.hbm.xml

```
<key column="id" not-null="true"/>
```

, and in authority.hbm.xml you replace the column username with

```
<property name="userId" column="userId"/>
```

You also have to modify the database table then.

Comment: thank you for advice,bit I've got:`java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'username' cannot be null` when create User

Comment: I added some text to my answer after your comment; please see above.

Comment: Johanna,as I understand from solution #2, I should add `userId` property to `User` class.Is it?

Comment: No. In the table User you already have this id (there it simply is called 'id'). For solution 2) you should add the column userId to the table Authority and drop the former column Username from Authority. You do not change the table User; for User you only change the mapping, set authorithies, different column in `<key >`.

Comment: ok, I see.Looks like solution #2 is not suited for me,because I afraid to change Authority table,that is standard Spring Security table

Comment: Yes, then you can't do solution 2). Now I guess Users also is a Spring security table. In this case you have to do solution 1) anyway, because you can't map a column which does not exist in the table (see [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html) for the Spring security tables. The key column is username. Both `<ìd>` and `<property>` map to database table columns. I'll add the complete mapping for solution 1).

Answer (score 1):

the error seems to come from the authority mapping. change it to have a backreference

Edit: you can use propertyref to tell H to join on another property

```
<class name="entry.Authority" table="authorities">
    <id name="id"/>
    <many-to-one name="user" column="username" property-ref="username"/>
</class>

and 

<set name="authorities" inverse="true" property-ref="username">
```

Comment: Firo,thank you for hint.Could you,please see EDITED section.That's my new config.Got exception:`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: entry.Authority column: username (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Answer (score 0):

if using JPA syntax will be like this (make owning side non-updatable):-

```
@JoinColumn(name = "", referencedColumnName = "", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

Issue is bi-directional relationship tries to update the column once again